# jquery youtube plugin - calling methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery Youtube plugin to embed a youtube video and use some of the API methods with the video.

I have the following code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#player").tubeplayer({
        width: 600, // the width of the player
        height: 450, // the height of the player
        allowFullScreen: "true", // true by default, allow user to go full screen
        initialVideo: "VIDEO_ID", // the video that is loaded into the player
        preferredQuality: "default",// preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720
        onPlay: function(id){}, // after the play method is called
        autoPlay: true,
        onPause: function(){}, // after the pause method is called
        onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
        onSeek: function(time){}, // after the video has been seeked to a defined point
        onMute: function(){}, // after the player is muted
        onUnMute: function(){}, // after the player is unmuted
        onPlayerEnded: function(){alert('ENDED')},
    });
</script>
```

This plays the video fine, but when the video has ended, I'd expect the `onPlayerEnded()` function to kick in and give me an `alert('Ended')`, which it doesn't.

Has anyone used this plugin before point me in any direction as to why this is the case?

Many thanks

Comment: is it ok you put that last comma in onPlayerEnded?

Comment: Only IE may have problem with the last comma

Comment: IE 7,8 and 9 all do not display the video. Even with SWFObject config added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine, may be a problem with you browser, try to use console.log instead of alert and check you console.

i put your code in a jsfiddle and it works
http://jsfiddle.net/sabri/wHpmM/

Comment: Using Chrome, seems to fix the problem and I'm now seeing the alert

Comment: This looks like it is a bug in FireFox 8/9 on ubuntu 11.10. It works FF on mac os x 10.7 and Chrome and IE, just not FF in ubuntu, which is strange.