# jquery youtube plugin - videos in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, video

Yesterday I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8589352/) about a jQuery YouTube Plugin. Having fixed that problem, I now notice that using this plugin doesn't load the video in Internet Explorer 7 or 8.

I made some minor tweaks and put the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4jeW/34/).

I'm including the SWFObject, which it says I need to in order to view in IE, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be loading the video.

Does anyone have an idea?

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="test">
     <p>Thank you for watching the video.</p>
     <p>Your Voucher Code is: <br /><br /><span>ABCDEFG</span></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.test').hide();
});

    jQuery("#player").tubeplayer({
    width: 600, // the width of the player
    height: 450, // the height of the player
    allowFullScreen: "true", // true by default, allow user to go full screen
    swfobjectURL: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js",
    loadSWFObject: true, // if you include swfobject, set to false
    initialVideo: "VIDEO_ID", // the video that is loaded into the player
    preferredQuality: "default",// preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720
    onPlay: function(id){}, // after the play method is called
    autoPlay: true,
    onPause: function(){}, // after the pause method is called
    onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
    onSeek: function(time){}, // after the video has been seeked to a defined point
    onMute: function(){}, // after the player is muted
    onUnMute: function(){}, // after the player is unmuted
    onPlayerEnded: function(){$('#player').hide(); $('.test').show(); }});
```

Comment: Feel free to downvote, but I have to comment :) Simply put, because IE is the biggest crap of software ever made!

Comment: I'm aware of that, but 95% of my userbase use IE (6-9). I cannot simply ignore this.

Comment: Yeah I know. Been there a few times. It would be soooo much easier if that crap never existed :) Anyway, for videos and cross-browser compatibility check out http://videojs.com/ Tried it just for test, and I was very satisfied. I know that is not what you are looking for, but maybe it helps somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I included [SWFObject 2.1](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js) and re-installed Flash player.

This now works in IE7, IE8 and IE9

Thanks for everyone's help :)